# How can I use a lambda expression to get both the property "path" and the value?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, lambda

I want to do something similar to what the HtmlHelpers do in ASP.NET MVC.  Take the following:

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.SomeProperty.SomeInnerProperty)
```

The HtmlHelper can clearly get not only the value for SomeInnerProperty, but it also knows what I call the "path" to that property because it creates the appropriate HTML element with an attribute:

```
name="SomeProperty.SomeInnerProperty"
```

I want to do be able to create a method that can get both the value and the "path" similar to how the HtmlHelpers do.  I did a little reflection into the existing HtmlHelpers and that looked like quite a rabbit hole.  I have been able to create a method that consumes it like so:

```
MyCustomMethod(model => model.SomeProperty.SomeInnerProperty);

private void MyCustomMethod(Expression<Func<object, object>> expression)
{
    // I can inspect the expression object in the debugger here
}
```

When inspecting the "expression" object, I can figure things out through reflection, but I'm not sure how robust my solution would be because I am just figuring things out through observation.  In addition, it just seems harder than it should be; like I am missing something simple.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

To get the complete path:

`expression.Body.ToString()` will give you 'model.SomeProperty.SomeInnerProperty'. Get a substring after first dot to get 'SomeProperty.SomeInnerProperty'.

To get the value:

`expression.Compile().Invoke(modelObject);`

Comment: Thanks, @gp.  I should have mentioned that I had seen expression.Body.ToString(), but I felt a little dirty having to parse that and wasn't sure that I could count on it.  Sounds like I can count on it.  I like your method to get the value.

Comment: Expression.ToString implementation does the same using ExpressionStringBuilder http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/Microsoft/Scripting/Ast/Expression.cs#02b69d6c264d6a31 . Then why not reuse it than write own implementation...

Answer (score 2):

```cs
//basic
MemberExpression memberExpression = (MemberExpression) expression.Body;
string name = (memberExpression.Expression as MemberExpression).Member.Name;
name += "." + memberExpression.Member.Name;

//cycle
MemberExpression memberExpression = (MemberExpression) expression.Body;
string name = "";
while (memberExpression.Expression is MemberExpression)
{
    name = memberExpression.Member.Name + "." + name;
    memberExpression = (MemberExpression)memberExpression.Expression;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Alexandr.  I should have mentioned that this will be some generic code that I want to work with not only model.SomeProperty.SomeInnerProperty, but also model.SomeProperty or model.SomeProperty.SomeInnerProperty.SomeInnerInnerProperty.  Your solution was part of what I found through observation as well, but it helps in that I didn't know I could easily cast things as MemberExpression to inspect properties vs. using full reflection.  I'll need to look for nulls or something to determine how deep to go.

Comment: I think I like this better than expression.Body.ToString() mentioned by @gp, but he/she helped with how to get the value.  I'll see if I get any more responses, but both answers so far may deserve a green checkmark.